# How does tvtak work for real-time content recognition for TV broadcast channel?

Tags: image-processing, video-streaming, computer-vision, broadcast, television

[tvtak](http://www.tvtak.com/) is a platform for TV content recognition.
It can auto-recognize real-time broadcast and offline advertising video.
Tvtak's core technology should be the real-time image matching between front-end image(from tv viewer's phone camera)
and backend frame images(from real-time capturing broadcast frame).
The question is :

**1. How tvtak can get the real-time broadcast channels stream?**. We know the channels are encrypted by cable operator! Does tvtak need to corporate with cable operator? Or do they get the video from some free internet broadcast stream?

**2. What may be the matching algorithm for tvtak?**

**3. How do tvtak get the electronic program guideline (EPG) for all channels**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. http://www.tvtak.com/developers.html says they take the real-time streams and index them on-the-fly:

   > Live TV -In the back-office, TvTak indexes in real-time broadcast TV
   >   channels in multiple countries. Video is not recorded but only
   >   analyzed in real-time to produce the reference matching identifiers.
   >
   > - Cues for Pre-recorded Clips – for ad spots, movie trailers, or any other pre-recorded content, reference IDs can be generated in advance.
2. I doubt anyone will tell you the algorithm
3. Why do they need the EPG? They have the live streams, which include things like "programme name" as meta-data (I assume!)

Comment: Thanks Martin, About question 1, i guess you mean tvtak will collect TV live stream by itself hardware (Satellite receiver + TV Card). is that right? question 3,I guess ,you are right ,MPEG 4.. can contain the EPG data.

Comment: @tihuBird: 1) Your guess is as good as mine, I have no direct knowledge of what they do.  If it were me I'd fit a load of PCs with DVB-S cards and plug them straight to a dish.